# Realvnc on Ubuntu 20.04 server 64bit : cannot currently show the desktop

Tags: server, 20.04, gui, vnc

Installed Ubuntu 20.04 64bit version on Raspberry

RealVNC show me this message: cannot currently show the desktop

Installed desktop manager:

```
~$ systemctl status display-manager.service
● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-03-17 08:27:07 UTC; 1h 3min ago
       Docs: man:lightdm(1)
   Main PID: 1867 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 17 08:27:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Mar 17 08:27:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Mar 17 08:27:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 17 08:27:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 17 08:27:07 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
```

when i try to start x11vnc i got these errors:

```
~$ sudo x11vnc

17/03/2022 09:27:07 x11vnc version: 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05  pid: 5998
17/03/2022 09:27:07 XOpenDisplay("") failed.
17/03/2022 09:27:07 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
17/03/2022 09:27:07 
17/03/2022 09:27:07 *** XOpenDisplay failed. No -display or DISPLAY.
17/03/2022 09:27:07 *** Trying ":0" in 4 seconds.  Press Ctrl-C to abort.
17/03/2022 09:27:07 *** 1 2 3 4 
17/03/2022 09:27:11 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
17/03/2022 09:27:11 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
17/03/2022 09:27:11 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
17/03/2022 09:27:11 Trying again with unset XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME ...
17/03/2022 09:27:11 

17/03/2022 09:27:11 ***************************************
17/03/2022 09:27:11 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:0)
```

also, this is what happen when i try to run vnclicensewiz:

```
~$ vnclicensewiz
VNC Server Licensing 6.7.2 (r43081) ARMv8-A (Sep 20 2020 23:41:22)
Copyright (C) 2002-2020 RealVNC Ltd.
RealVNC and VNC are trademarks of RealVNC Ltd and are protected by trademark
registrations and/or pending trademark applications in the European Union,
United States of America and other jurisdictions.
Protected by UK patent 2481870; US patent 8760366; EU patent 2652951.
See https://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
For third party acknowledgements see:
https://www.realvnc.com/docs/6/foss.html
OS: Ubuntu 20.04, Linux 5.4.0, aarch64
<11> 2022-03-17T10:27:26.838Z ubuntu vnclicensewiz[9255]: main: unable to open display ""
<11> 2022-03-17T10:27:26.838Z ubuntu vnclicensewiz[9255]: TXMsgBox: unable to open display ""
<11> 2022-03-17T10:27:26.838Z ubuntu vnclicensewiz[9255]: TXMsgBox: unable to open display ""
unable to open display ""
```